# Is there any way in ALM REST how to access test parameters?

Tags: rest, testing, configuration, parameters, alm

I am developing an application that is supposed to retrieve test parameters from test instances in ALM, submit them in tests and then update statuses in ALM. Problem is I do not know how to access these parameters from REST API.
As close as I got was test configuration in /qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/test-configs/ but this does not contain data I need.

Answer (score 2):

its a little bit later to answer, but hope it will help someday.

http://{{SERVERNAME}}/qcbin/rest/domains/{{DOMAIN}}/projects/{{PROJECT}}/test-parameters?fields=*&query=%7Bparent-id%5B{{test_id}}%5D%7D

this will return XML or JSON (depends on Accept: header) with params data